# Excel VBA - debugging invokes functions not used in selected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

While debugging a certain sub which works on a certain sheet, pressing F8 step by step, I realized that I went on to functions that are not used in that particular sheet. Why is that? Also, will Excel go thru those functions even when not in debug mode?

Comment: They are possibly being called by event-triggered macros.  If that is the case, then yes, they will, although they will probably not do anything.

Comment: If there are UDF functions in place and your code modify something triggering the `Calculate` event, it is a normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, these features don't bother you. They may at most spoil readability.
In fact, sometimes this can happen when you use a lot of different macros.